# how to overwrite drupal default message when posting comments?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I would like to overwrite a default message for posting a comment.

For example, I would like to display "*Your comment has been sent to the site moderator and will remain private.*" instead of "*Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.*"

I tried hook insert, but it didn't override the message:

```
function custom_comment_insert($comment) {
    //drupal_get_messages(null, true);
    unset($_SESSION['messages']);
    drupal_set_message(t('override like this.'));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use that, use [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) to change the message instead. In general, if you want to reword text, don't hack it, override it.

In Drupal 7, you can use `settings.php` to change it directly: (See http://preprocess.me/drupal-override-strings-in-settingsphp)

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en']['Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.'] = 'Your comment has been sent to the site moderator and will remain private.';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The String Overrides module worked for me.

Comment: [String overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) or `settings.php` don't work if one wants to do this programatically (e.g. inside a custom module).

Answer (score 4):

@Maciej Zgadzaj Your solution works fine as well. 
I found a useful tutorial on hook_form_alter http://bit.ly/12u09O

```
function private_comments_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
switch($form_id) {
        case 'comment_node_proposed_rules_form':
            unset($form['field_comment_public']);
        $form['#submit'][] = 'private_comments_comments_form_submit';
        //$form['#submit'][]='my_submit_test';
        break;
}
}
function private_comments_comments_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
unset($_SESSION['messages']);
drupal_set_message("this is a form test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is being added to session in `comment_form_submit()`, AFTER new comment is saved.

So either you alter comment form, add your own submit function after the main one, and remove the message there (which seems to be a better idea, as this way this is going to be done only when a new comment is really posted), or...

Actually, no 'or'. Originally wanted to suggest something like `hook_init()` as an alternative, but no, you don't want to put it there. ;)

Comment: Would this count as hacking the core of drupal as I'm modifying htdocs/modules/comments/comment.module

Comment: @Vlad Vinnikau: Don't alter `comment.module`.  Copy the submit function to your own module, change the message to what you want it to say, and use a `hook_form_alter` so that your function is called instead of the default one.

Comment: No no no, bad idea, NOT instead. Just add your own submit to the original one, DO NOT replace. In your form_alter() you can just do something like: $form['#submit'][] = 'your_submit_function_name';

Answer (score 0):

There is question over at [Drupal Answers SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88572/how-do-i-alter-a-message-in-the-message-queue-independent-of-site-language) where the solution given is to use `array_search()` to search the actual message array, and then compare the translated strings to identify the key of the string to alter.  Then showing how to alter it.

This solution works when implemented as part of a module, while changing the message string in the setting file does not.